# Android: Mediaplayer Error Could not play on client side

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play a video from a url on my device (Google Nexus-4) but whenever I run my app it gives me a message of can't play this video. Here is my code

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        String str = "http://mywebsite.com/456-sd-sdss.mp4";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

And here is my logcat

```
D/MediaPlayer(29745): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer(29745): error (1, -1004)
E/MediaPlayer(29745): Error (1,-1004)
D/VideoView(29745): Error: 1,-1004
```